# Looking to optimize the following JQuery code

Tags: jquery, html, filter, switch-statement, parents

I have 4 floated divs, when you hover over the A tag inside the divs, a div will show up at the bottom of these 4 divs which corresponds to the div where the click happenned. I have optimized the JQuery to the best of my knowledge, but I just wanted to see if there are other solutions out there.

**My Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/jonxblaze/PyHH5/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="promo red">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

    <p><a href="#">More</a></p>
</div> 
<div class="promo yellow">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

    <p><a href="#">More</a></p>
</div>    
<div class="promo blue">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

    <p><a href="#">More</a></p>
</div>
 <div class="promo black">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

    <p><a href="#">More</a></p>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

```
<div class="red wide-full">RED CONTENTS</div>
<div class="yellow wide-full">YELLOW CONTENTS</div>
<div class="blue wide-full">BLUE CONTENTS</div>
<div class="black wide-full">BLACK CONTENTS</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.yellow.wide-full, .blue.wide-full, .black.wide-full').hide();

$('.promo a').hover( function() {

            var parentDiv = $(this).parents().filter('.promo'),
                wideFull  = $('.wide-full');    

            switch (true) { 
                case parentDiv.hasClass('red'):
                    $('.red.wide-full').show();
                    wideFull.not('.red').hide();
                    break; 
                case parentDiv.hasClass('yellow'):
                    $('.yellow.wide-full').show();
                    wideFull.not('.yellow').hide();
                    break;                  
                case parentDiv.hasClass('blue'):
                    $('.blue.wide-full').show();
                    wideFull.not('.blue').hide();
                    break; 
                case parentDiv.hasClass('black'): 
                    $('.black.wide-full').show();
                    wideFull.not('.black').hide();
                    break;  
            }
        })
```

Comment: `$('.wide-full').hide()` should be sufficient but it doesn't really make a huge performance difference. p/s: I discourage users from using appearance as class names, i.e. "blue", "yellow" because it is not context specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also make use of `data` attributes to reference corresponding divs:

```
$('.wide-full:not(.red)').hide();

$('.promo a').hover(function() {
    $('.wide-full').hide().filter('.' + $(this).data('type')).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PyHH5/3/

For this I modified HTML a little bit:

```
<a href="#" data-type="yellow">More</a>
```

Comment: Very simple, this is exactly what I was hoping to get. Thanks!